# Music commands in discord bot using discord.py rewrite

Tags: discord, discord.py

I've recently created a bot with the default kick and ban commands along with some other things. However, one thing I've really want to add is music commands. For example, `.play <song name>` would a the selected song. and `.pause` and `.stop` would pause and stop the music playing. Any tips or links to videos would really be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Unfortunately, I don't know how to make a song stop or pause, but if I will find out how to do it I will edit this answer.

```
import discord
import os
import youtube_dl
import asyncio

from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 1234567890 #change this to your token 

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".") #Here you can change prefix for commands

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
}   

def endSong(guild, path):
    os.remove(path)                                   

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url):
    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send('You are not connected to a voice channel') #message when you are not connected to any voice channel
        return

    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel

    voice_client = await channel.connect()

    guild = ctx.message.guild

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        file = ydl.extract_info(url, download=True)
        path = str(file['title']) + "-" + str(file['id'] + ".mp3")

    voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(path), after=lambda x: endSong(guild, path))
    voice_client.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice_client.source, 1)

    await ctx.send(f'**Music: **{url}') #sends info about song playing right now


client.run(TOKEN)
```

### Optional, useful function

If you want you can make your bot leave the voice channel after the song/music stop playing. Add this at the end of your code, but before ***client.run(TOKEN)***!

```
while voice_client.is_playing():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    else:
        await voice_client.disconnect()
        print("Disconnected")
```

### How to use it

.play *url* - plays song from url (*example* .play https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)